# Display text and data R markdown shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Yesterday I tried to write my first interactive markdown document with R studio and finally it worked ok, but I can not figure out how to access the data inside a render plot(). It is probably very easy, but I can not find the right examples. May be some kind soul will help me?

I am trying to illustrate the central limit theorem with this code

````
---
title: "Eksperimentering med utvalg"
author: "Per G. Østerlie"
date: "15 3 2017"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


# CLT


```{r}
fisk_masse =sample(1:1000,500,replace=TRUE)

```
```{r histogram, echo=FALSE}
hist(fisk_masse, 
     main="Masse i populasjon", 
     xlab="Masse", 
     ylab="Antall",
     border="darkgray", 
     col="lightgray",
     xlim=c(0,1000),
     las=1, 
     breaks=10)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
paste("Gjennomsnitt: ",mean(fisk_masse))
paste("Standardavvik: ",sd(fisk_masse))
```

# Sample

50 fish, choose number of samples

```{r, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  sliderInput("n_utvalg", label = "Antall utvalg",
              min = 50, max = 800, value = 100, step = 50)
)
renderPlot({
xbar = rep(0,input$n_utvalg)
for (i in 1:input$n_utvalg){xbar[i]=mean(sample(fisk_masse,50,replace=FALSE))}
hist(xbar, 
     main="Gjennomsnittsmasse i stikkprovene", 
     xlab="Masse", 
     ylab="Antall",
     border="darkgray", 
     col="lightgray",
     #xlim=c(0,1000),
     las=1, 
     breaks=10)

m <-mean(xbar)
std<-sqrt(var(xbar))

})
````

Now I would like to display the variables m (or mean(xbar) and std. I would like to have them displayed under the histogram. All my attempts end up with a message that xbar is not known (which make sense). Can anyone direct me to an answer?

Per

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Shiny, you will have to render text similarly to how you render a plot when the input is dynamic. So additionally to `renderPlot()` you will also have to add a `renderText()` part to your last chunk.

I recommend computing `xbar` in a so called reactive conductor. With the help of the reactive conductor you only have to compute `xbar` once for the plot and the text output.

You can replace your last chunk with this working example:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}

    inputPanel(
      sliderInput("n_utvalg", label = "Antall utvalg",
                  min = 50, max = 800, value = 100, step = 50)
    ) 
  computeXbar <- reactive({
    xbar = rep(0,input$n_utvalg)
    for (i in 1:input$n_utvalg){xbar[i]=mean(sample(fisk_masse,50,replace=FALSE))}
    xbar
  })

  renderPlot({
    xbar <- computeXbar()
    hist(xbar,
         main="Gjennomsnittsmasse i stikkprovene",
         xlab="Masse",
         ylab="Antall",
         border="darkgray",
         col="lightgray",
         #xlim=c(0,1000),
         las=1,
         breaks=10)

    })

  renderText({
    xbar <- computeXbar()
    paste(
      "The mean is: ", mean(xbar), " and the standard deviation is ", sqrt(var(xbar))
    )
  })

```
````

You can find more information about Shiny reactivity in this overview article: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html